# Change the default size of square brackets in latex math mode

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

Personally I think the default size of square brackets in latex math mode is too small. For example, for an interval `[a,b]`, I would prefer `\big[\big]` as opposed to plain `[]`. My question is, what can I do to change the default size of `[]`, so that when I input `[]` in math mode, they will show up automatically the same size as `\big[\big]`?

Right now I'm defining a new command called `\b{}` which takes one argument and inserts it between `\big[` and `\big]`, but the code looks ugly. Apparently `\newcommand` (or `\def` or `\let`) does not allow `[` to be refined.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load a scaled version of the relevant font and substitute the standard definitions for `[` and `]`.  Below I have chosen a scaling of `1.2` over the standard size for some exaggeration, probably you only want a factor of `1.1`

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmrlop}{}

\newcommand{\mybscale}{1.2}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmrlop}{m}{n}%
     {<5><6><7><8><9><10><12>gen*[\mybscale]cmr%
      <10.95>*[\mybscale]cmr10%
      <14.4>*[\mybscale]cmr12%
      <17.28><20.74><24.88>*[\mybscale]cmr17}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{loperators}{OT1}{cmrlop}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{[}{\mathopen}{loperators}{"5B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{]}{\mathclose}{loperators}{"5D}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen}{loperators}{"5B}{largesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{loperators}{"5D}{largesymbols}{"03}

\begin{document}

\( [a,b] \)

\begin{displaymath}
\left[a,c\right] \bigl[a,b\bigr] \Bigl[a,b\Bigr] \biggl[a,b\biggr] \Biggl[a,b\Biggr]
\end{displaymath}

\( ([()]) \)

\end{document}
```

The code adjusts the normal size of the brackets, but not the large scaled versions.  You would have to apply similar techniques to the `largesymbols` family to change those.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {loperators}{"5B}{largesymbols}{"02}` be safer?

Comment: @campa Thanks.  I think we need both, your code is relevant for `\left...\right`.

Comment: Thanks guys I believe that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could define `\[` as `\big[` and `\]` as `\big]`, the problem is that `\[\]` are already defined to open and close the displaystyle math mode environment so one has to undefine them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \let\[\@undefined
    \let\]\@undefined
\makeatother

\def\[{\big[}
\def\]{\big]}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \[a,b\]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the already-available `\[` `\]`? The whole document will be messed up. At least one should find a different name for the macro. Redefining one of the most important macro in LaTeX doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: @JouleV Totally agree, but the author wanted something that didn't change the syntax of the parentheses. That's the closest thing that I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own command (not `\b` because it has been already defined) to achieve your objective.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\brakets}[1]{\ensuremath{\bigg[#1\bigg]}}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $[31]$ original\\
    \brakets{31} something something something...\\
    \brakets{xyz} something something something...\\
    $\brakets{xyz} + x = \cdots$ in mathmode as well\\
\end{document}
```